# Benchmark in GHCi, how can I enable to show number of reductions for expression?

Tags: haskell, ghci, haskell-platform

I am playing with GHCi and I wondering how can I enable in GHCi to raise the number of reduction in expression to compare different solutions?

Comment: Keep in mind that the performance in GHCi can be vastly different from the one obtained by compiling the code with GHC and turning optimization on. If you want serious benchmarking, compile the code and use something like `criterion`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hugs had (has?) such an option.

In GHCi, you can enter `Prelude> :set +s` to print rough timings after each evaluation. Then apply [empirical orders of growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth) analysis as needed.

For proper testing compile with the -O2 flag, and run standalone executables at your shell prompt with "+RTS -s" option to get the stats. Also, there's Criterion package.